# What is difference between truth-functional inconsistency and non-truth-functional inconsistency?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The statement:

> Jim is a bachelor and Jim (the same Jim) is married.

If we take,

**P:** Jim is a bachelor.

**Q:** Jim is married.

This statement is of the form **P ∧ Q** with truth-table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
p&q&p∧ q\\ \hline
T&T&T\\
T&F&F\\
F&T&F\\
F&F&F\\\hline
\end{array}$$

Well, truth-table clearly shows that it is truth-functional **contingent**, but at the same time it is impossible in a logical or conceptual sense. So, it is obviously **inconsistency** (and not contingent). But it is not **truth-functional inconsistency**, it is **non-truth-functional inconsistency**.

What is difference between them?

Comment: If you formalize the "atomic" sentences with two different *sentential letters* $P$ and $Q$, you have no way to take into account the fact that the two sentences "speak of" the *same* Jim.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA this example is given in schaum's outline as example for Non-Truth-Inconsistency.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I haven't reached at predicate calculus yet.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but it is consider contradiction only if all the operators of '∧' are 'F' (false). That's why I gave truth table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See page 62 of [Schaum's *Outline*](https://books.google.it/books?id=dNKsBAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) :

> The statement ‘Jim is a bachelor and Jim (the same Jim) is married’, for example, has the propositional form ‘"$B \land M$", and hence is *truth-functionally contingent*, as this truth table reveals.
>
> But this statement [it means : in natural language] is inconsistent, not contingent; what it asserts is impossible in a logical or conceptual sense. Its inconsistency, however, is *non-truth-functional*, being a consequence of the semantics of the
> expressions ‘is a bachelor’ and ‘is married’, in addition to the logical operator ‘and’.

As you noted, the truth-table for "and" applied to the statement $B \land M$ does not show a contradiction (nor a tautology) and thus the truth-functional symbolization of the natural language statement is *contingent*.

In order to show the inconsistency of the natural language statement, it is not enough the truth-functional symbolization available with propositional logic.

What we need is a "deeper" level of analysis that consider also

> the semantics of the expressions ‘is a bachelor’ and ‘is married’, in addition to the logical operator ‘and’.

This will available wit *predicate logic* where we can analyze the "atomic" sentences with a subject-predicate logical form :

> $\text {Bachelor}(\text {Jim})$ and $\text {Married}(\text {Jim})$.

With the tools of predicate logic, we may further express the "logical or conceptual" link implicit into the semantics of the expressions ‘is a bachelor’ and ‘is married’, that means to consider the "definitional axiom" :

> $\text {Bachelor}(x) \text {  iff  } \lnot \text {Married}(x)$.

In this way, from $\text {Bachelor}(\text {Jim}) \land \text {Married}(\text {Jim})$ we may derive the *non-truth-functional* [i.e. not expressible in propositional logic] contradiction :

> > $\lnot \text {Married}(\text {Jim}) \land \text {Married}(\text {Jim})$.

See page 63 :

> if a wff is truth-functionally contingent, then it is contingent *only so far as the operators represented in the wff are concerned*. Some specific statements of the form will be genuinely contingent, while others will be non-truth-functionally necessary or inconsistent as a result of factors not represented in the wff.

Comment: Thank you so much!